# Create Kubernetes Secrets from Azure Keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, csi-driver

I am trying to create kubernetes secrets by retrieving the secret data from azure keyvault.

I know that there is the **secrets store csi driver**, but this plugin allows me to read secrets from KeyVault, and make them available as volume mounts only, but not kubernetes secrets.

The problem is, I use some kubernetes custom resource, which takes the k8s secret name in a field and then retrieve data from k8s secrets internally.

So, I need to be abe to create a kubernetes secret from data obtained from Azure Keyvault. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an operator called [Azure Key Vault to Kubernetes](https://github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes).

it has a piece called `Azure Key Vault Controller` which can help you do that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Azure Redhat Open shift (ARO).
It has required to connect with Azure key vault. I have applied the following process to configure it.

We need to download open shift cli for windows [Link1](https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v4/clients/ocp/latest/?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001Css5AAC)
Now extract zip file and move oc.exc into `C:\Program Files\oc\oc.exc`
Add this path into your environment variable.

Now open your command prompt execute the following command

```
oc login https://api.<your ARO server>.aroapp.io:6443 -u kubeadmin

oc new-project k8s-secrets-store-csi

oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged \
  system:serviceaccount:k8s-secrets-store-csi:secrets-store-csi-driver

helm repo add secrets-store-csi-driver \
  https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver/charts

helm repo update

helm install -n k8s-secrets-store-csi csi-secrets-store \
  secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver \
  --version v1.0.1 \
  --set "linux.providersDir=/var/run/secrets-store-csi-providers"

kubectl --namespace=k8s-secrets-store-csi get pods -l "app=secrets-store-csi-driver"

helm repo add csi-secrets-store-provider-azure \
  https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/charts

helm repo update

helm install -n k8s-secrets-store-csi azure-csi-provider \
  csi-secrets-store-provider-azure/csi-secrets-store-provider-azure \
  --set linux.privileged=true --set secrets-store-csi-driver.install=false \
  --set "linux.providersDir=/var/run/secrets-store-csi-providers" \
  --version=v1.0.1

oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged \
  system:serviceaccount:k8s-secrets-store-csi:csi-secrets-store-provider-azure

oc new-project my-application
```

Now create a service principal and give the access to the key vault

```
kubectl create secret generic secrets-store-creds \
  -n my-application \
  --from-literal clientid=${SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_ID} \
  --from-literal clientsecret=${SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_SECRET}
kubectl -n my-application label secret \
  secrets-store-creds secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/used=true
```